# Verify if the following sets are linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm asked to determine if the following sets are linear subspaces:

$$\{{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x=t^5, y=3t^5,t\in\mathbb{R}}\}$$

and

$$\{{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x=t^2, y=3t^2,t\in\mathbb{R}}\}$$

To verify this, I first check if $(0,0)$ belongs to both sets. By setting $t=0$, it does.

However, I don't really know how to check for the sum or multiplication by a scalar. For example, for $t=1$, in both sets we get (1, 3). However, I don't think $(1,3)+(1,3)=(2,6)$ belongs to either set.

My textbook says the first set is a subspace, while the second one isn't. In both cases I guess I could factor the parameter like this: $t^5(1,3)^{tr}$ (which happens to be a basis for the first set). Any hints on how to check if they are subspaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hints

**For the first set:** Since the function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R: t\mapsto t^5$ is bijective, the first set is the same as $$\{{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x=t, y=3t,t\in\mathbb{R}}\}.$$

**For the second set:** Let $$S:=\{{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x=t^2, y=3t^2,t\in\mathbb{R}}\}$$
We have $(1,3)\in S$, but do we have $(-1,-3)\in S$?

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to formally prove this without recurring to examples? Or maybe if the Professor asks to "determine" and not give proof that's enough.

Comment: Proving what exactly? Something about the first or something about the second set?

Comment: Proving that any negative $(x,y)$ doesn't belong to $S$.

Comment: It suffices. A subspace must have additive inverses by definition. Maximilian has produced an element in S without an additive inverse, so S is not a subspace.

Comment: Thanks. For the first set should I just prove it's a subspace formally? For example by picking two generic vectors in the set and checking if their sum belongs to the subspace?

Comment: As at @NicholasRoberts pointed out, my counter-example is, even in the most formal context, a [valid proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Proof_by_Counterexample). You can also note that $t^2\geq 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$ which means that $$x<0\text{ or } y<0\implies (x,y)\not\in S$$

Comment: @Cesare Yes, that is correct for the first set. But you also need to prove that $r\cdot(x,y)$ is in the set for all $r$ in $\mathbb R$ and $(x,y)$ in the set.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Would $r(x,y) = (rx,ry)=(rt^5,3rt^5)=r(t^5,3t^5)=r(x,y)\in{S}$ work you think?

Comment: And for the sum $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(t^5,3t^5)+(t^5,3t^5)=(2t^5,6t^5)=2(t^5,3t^5)=2(x,y)\in{S}$

Comment: @Cesare The idea is that $$r\cdot(x,y)=(rt^5,3rt^5)=(\tilde t^5, 3\tilde t^5),$$ where $\tilde t=\sqrt[5]{r}\cdot t$. And for the sum: $$(t_1^5,3t_1^5)+(t_2^5,3t_2^5)=(\tilde t^5,3\tilde t^5)$$ where $\tilde t=\sqrt[5]{t_1^5+t_2^5}$.